# Parental control software for iPhone11 and Apple devices in general

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, parental-controls

- Apple is known for the hard restriction of privacy which makes it hard to get lots of deep monitoring (or spying) features such as reading social messages to work on non jail-broken devices.
- iOS14 is equipped with built-in ScreenTime app, but this only lets you schedule the on and off times, with no ability for manual on-demand blocking or allowing.
- I have tried OurPact, but it didn't work. Dashboard said the device is blocked - I'm holding it in my hand and it is wide open.

Are there any applications that give the parent sufficient control & monitoring, that is trusted and not a malware, that simply work with no issues? I'll take the best thing out there that brings maximum value on non-jail broken iphone device.

Problem is that all searches both in Google & Duckduckgo all lead to all kinds of listings made by affiliated marketers, but no references or reviews from real people. All these products require subscription with no trial to see that it actually works.

Are there somewhere real testimonies of real people which deployed and enjoyed high quality parental control systems on their children iphone's and are live to tell about it?

Comment: I would take a look at the MDM software available at JAMF, especially [JAMF Now](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/).

Comment: Just checked out the demo and it seems not quite what I'm looking for. no screen time limitation abilities, no visibility inside the messages. This solution is not for parenting but for IT Admin for phones provided to employees in organizations. it lets you manage the applications inside no more than that.

Comment: With regards to social media, you could simply authenticate the relevant accounts on another phone or computer (you can use another web browser profile to keep the cookies separate from your own). This won't work if the sessions are de-authenticated, for example by changing the account password.